# Arc Length parametrized by $r(t) = (\cos(e^t),\sin(e^t),e^t)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Using the vector valued function given by: $\mathbf r(t)=[\cos(e^t), \sin(e^t), e^t]$, for $0 \le t \le t$, compute the arc length.

I have the derivatives of each component of the vector and I know that the arc length is computed by taking the integral of the square root of the distance formula. I just don't know how to how to simplify what is under the square root in order to take the integral. Please help!

Comment: see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot3d+%28cos+exp%28t%29%2C+sin+exp%28t%29%2C+exp+t%29%2C+0%3Ct%3C1

Comment: @janmarqz how does that help OP simplify his/ her expression?

Comment: What do you have for your path length integral?

Comment: @user186765 We need to see what you've gotten so far.

Comment: maybe for something

Comment: @user186765 Just in case you haven't seen Amitai's notation before, your integral should be $s=\int_0^1 \sqrt{(\frac {\partial f}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac {\partial f}{\partial y})^2 + (\frac {\partial f}{\partial z})^2}dt = \int_0^1 \sqrt{(\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}, \frac {\partial f}{\partial z}) \cdot (\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}, \frac {\partial f}{\partial z})}dt = \int_0^1 \|\mathbf {\dot r}(t)\|dt = \int_0^1 \|\mathbf v(t)\|dt = \int_0^1 \|\frac {\partial \mathbf r(t)}{\partial t}\| dt$

Comment: They are all equivalent notations.

Answer (score 0):

$\dot{r}(t)=(-\sin(e^t)\cdot e^t,\cos(e^t)\cdot e^t,e^t)$,

$\|\dot{r}(t)\|^2=\sin^2(e^t)\cdot e^{2t}+\cos^2(e^t)\cdot e^{2t}+e^{2t}=2e^{2t}$,

$\|\dot{r}(t)\|=\sqrt{2}\cdot e^t$.